# Delete files in context menu with bat file windows 8

Tags: batch-file, menu, windows-8.1

my bat file:

@echo off
set targetfolder=%1
cd /d %1

del *.*
pause

my  delete.reg file

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Run Batch script]
@="Delete all"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Run Batch script\command]
@=C:\delete.bat \"%V\"

The option is in the context menu but if I click Im getting this error:

This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action. Please install a program or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Programs control panel.

[OK]

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a batch file, you should be able to run a command directly from the registry key.
Example:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "SKEY=HKCU\Software\Classes\"
SET "EKEY=\shell\DeleteAll"
REG ADD %SKEY%Folder%EKEY% /VE /D "Delete &All Files" /F>NUL
REG ADD %SKEY%Folder%EKEY%\command /VE /T REG_EXPAND_SZ /D^
 "%%COMSPEC%% /C PUSHD %%L && DEL *.*" /F>NUL
```

Right-click on a folder and select 'Delete All Files' to delete all normal files within that folder. *(Be careful this will be catastrophic if you select the wrong folder)*